# Laravel: Insert in pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

I have 3 tables

```
User(id,name,email)
Role(id,rolename)
role_user(user_id,role_id)
```

In roles table i have following data;

```
id    rolename
1     admin
2     user
```

In this scenario, I have users table is associated to roles table with many to many relation.

I have one eloquent model as

```
UserModel
 user_roles(){
belongsToMany('Role')
 }
```

Now I want to save data in role_user table when i create user. I have roles in dropdown.

I am using following query

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = $data->username;
$user->email= $data->email
$user->save();
```

its perfectly saves the user in user table but i want also want to save data in user_role table.

Can you guys please help me how to save this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method after you create the user:

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

Comment: what is $roleId ?

Comment: @HaniMehdi `$roleId` is a role ID or array of role IDs. If you have this in the `$data`, just use `$data->roles`

Answer (score 0):

In User model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

In Role model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

I assume you pass the roles as an array, then in your controller you can have something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return $request->roles;
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'  => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required|confirmed'
    ]);

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = $request->password;

    $user->save();

    $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);

    return redirect()->route('backend.users');
}
```

Comment: thanks but it only save the record in users table not in leave_user table

Comment: This line should do the trick: $user->roles()->attach($request->roles);. By the way, what is "leave_user" table?

Comment: sorry its role_user table instead of leave_user

Comment: Again, use this "$user->roles()->attach($request->roles);" after saving the user. I have done this and it works.